# Auth0 login with linkedin get public profile URL

Tags: linkedin-api, auth0

I am using Auth0 Linkedin connector for signing in into my site.
How do i get the Linkedin public profile URL of the user?
It used to be part of the Linkedin r_basicprofile permissions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately LinkedIn locked it down.

Comment: Do you have sources?

Comment: unfortunately...